# How to enclose finding a node id in an if statement in accessibility services?

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm programming an android accessibility service, but am having troubles enclosing a findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId in an if statement.

The code below is the only way I can actually get the accessibility service to see the nodes. What I'd like is that if it finds nobutton to skip over the section for action_button

```
        @Override
        public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {


            if (AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED == event
                    .getEventType()) {
                AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();

                if (nodeInfo == null) {
                    return;
                }

                List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = nodeInfo
                        .findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.testapp.android:id/no_button");

                 for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {


                    Path swipePath = new Path();
                    swipePath.moveTo(1000, 400);
                    swipePath.lineTo(1000, 1000);
                    GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
                    gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(swipePath, 0, 100));
                    dispatchGesture(gestureBuilder.build(), null, null);
                }

                list = nodeInfo 
                       .findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.testapp.android:id/action_button");
                for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
                    node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
                }

            }

        }
```

Right now the code compiles and runs, but because there is another action_button in another part of the app that it is seeing, it clicks on that after scrolling, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = nodeInfo
                    .findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.testapp.android:id/no_button");

             for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {


                Path swipePath = new Path();
                swipePath.moveTo(1000, 400);
                swipePath.lineTo(1000, 1000);
                GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
                gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(swipePath, 0, 100));
                dispatchGesture(gestureBuilder.build(), null, null);
            }

            if(list.isEmpty()) {
                list = nodeInfo 
                   .findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.testapp.android:id/action_button");
                for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
                    node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.testapp.android:id/no_button");

if(list.size() > 0) {
  // true
} else {
  // false
}
```